# Local slopes from local regression

Tags: r

How to get the local slopes of a local regression fitted using Locfit package? Am I correct in using the following codes:

```
fit<- locfit(lny~lnx, data=rmc, deg=1, alpha=0.5, deriv=1)
fitted (fit,data=rmc,what="coef",cv=T,type="fit",deg=1)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are extracting are the fitted value: the points corresponding to your "xs" that are on the line in the graph. What exactly are you calling the coefficients?

Comment: When adding "deriv=1", the returned fit will be estimating the derivative (or an estimate of the local slope) - I found this instruction in the manual of Locfit. So I guess when I want to extract the local slope, I can use the fitted function. Please let me know if there is other way.

Comment: That sounds good. Feel free to post an answer to your own question for future reference

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question for future reference